# Como puedo rellenar los espacios que estan sobre la diagonal principal de una matriz?

Tags: java

Defina una tercera función que se llame Llenar_sobre, que recorra la diagonal principal de la
matriz dada como parámetro, calcule un aleatorio entre 5 y 40, si el aleatorio calculado es
mayor que el número que hay en la diagonal principal, lo debe poner en esa posición, de lo
contrario no.

Con este codigo hasta el momento solo tengo la matriz con su diagonal principal con valores aleatorios- mi duda es como relleno los espacios que van arriba de la diagonal principal

y aparte de ello como puedo hacer una funcion que sume todos los valores que hay en la ultima columna de la matriz, espero me puedan ayudar.

```
  import java.util.Random;
  import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
  public class Miercoles22 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        int[][]matriz;
        int filas, columnas;
        
        filas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite por favor el numero de filas que llevara la matriz: "));
        columnas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite por favor el numero de columnas que llevara la matriz: "));
        matriz = new int[filas][columnas];
        
        if (filas>=6 && columnas<=8) {
            Crear_Matriz(filas, columnas);
            Llenar_Diag_Ppal(matriz);
            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+"|");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            Llenar_sobre(matriz);
            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                    System.out.print(matriz[i][j]+"|");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("ERROR");
            
        }
    } catch (Exception error) {
        System.out.println("Ocurrió un error: \n" + error);
    } finally {
        System.out.println("Fin de la ejecucion");
    }
}
public static int[][] Crear_Matriz(int filas, int columnas){
    int[][] matriz=new int[filas][columnas];
    
    return matriz;
}
public static int[][] Llenar_Diag_Ppal(int[][]matriz){
    Random aleatorio = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
        matriz[i][i]=5+aleatorio.nextInt(15);
        }

   return matriz;
}
```